# Moving files of a particular File Extension from multiple folders into one specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm only started scripting a few weeks ago and have been testing a few scripts I've put together with help from some posted on this site.

Currently I'm struggling and require some help or assistance.

I want to be able to move all files with any particular/given file extension, from within any directory, and any of their sub-directories, *if they exist*. I just want the files, not the folders copied.

The script works, I'm hoping for anyway, as such:

1. You enter the directory you want to move the files from e.g. `D:\TestMove`
2. You enter the directory you want to move the files to e.g. `D:\Test`
3. You enter the file extension of all of the files that you want to be moved from the given directory, and then sub-directories eg. `.txt`

If the directory you're moving them to doesn't exist, it should be created.

So in my case, I've got the directory `D:\Test`, with multiple sub-directories, *(`TestMove\Test2`, etc.)*, and within each of those directories multiple `.txt` files, *(for example)*. I want to be able to move all of the `.txt` files from the `D:\Test` directory to wherever I want.

At the moment, it's just moving the files from the directory I choose, but not from within the sub-directories.

I'm happy to get this script ripped to bits so that I can learn where I'm going wrong.

```
set /P DMF=Please enter Directory moving from: 
set /P DMT=Please enter Directory moving too: 
set /P FEX=Please enter File Extension:

if not exist %DMT% mkdir %DMT%
for %%a in (%FEX%) do (
        echo Moving all %%a files to "%DMT%" ...
        move "%DMF%\*%%a" "%DMT%"
)
```

Comment: You should really modify your methodology. I would suggest you ask for the source and extension, then check that the source contains files of that extension. Only in that scenario should you think about asking for, and possibly creating, a missing destination. To check for the non existence of a directory, you should use `If Not Exist D:\irectory\ `, _(note the trailing backslash)_. It may also be worth mentioning that you could omit the directory check and subsequent creation, were you to use the `RoboCopy` command together with at least its `/Mov` option.

Comment: You might consider looking at `robocopy`, something like `robocopy /e /mov "source\folder" "dest\folder" *ext` should do what you're after.  I think.

Comment: type `for /?` and read it's output - especially the `/R` switch: `for /R "%DMF%" %%a in (*.%FEX%) do (` / `move "%%~fa" "%DMT\%"`. Note: you should be prepared for duplicate file names.